# Как отобразить содержимое объекта в сводке выполнения PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

При ошибке в тесте PHPUnit в командной строке выводит сводку и если были переданы данные через `dataProvider` тогда он также показывает какие данные. Это отлично работает с массивами, но объект закрыт для просмотра (см. скрин). Возможно ли как-то это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вывода кишок объекта нет и не предусмотрено, так как передаваемые объекты могут содержать в своих пропертях другие объекты, и в общем-то, уровень вложенности объектов в объекты не ограничен.

Экспортер от таких данных может просто повиснуть выжрав всю память.

Однако, к любому из ассертов можно назначить **кастомное сообщение об ошибке** и уже в это сообщение поместить данные тестируемого объекта. В данном случае можно либо вывести какие-то конкретные проперти объекта, либо создать магический метод `__toString` (если таковой не занят) и определить, что будет выводиться при касте объекта в строку:

```
// очень приблизительный вариант
$this->assertSame(2, $variable, "Значение переменной должно быть равно двум");
```

Comment: мм спасибо, полезная подсказка